# querying column from database and bind it

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand com,com2;
string str5 = "SELECT count(Name) as count from [Committee].[dbo].[Supervisor] ;";

com2 = new SqlCommand(str5, con);

SqlDataReader reader4 = com2.ExecuteReader();
int count= 0;

if (reader4.Read())
{
    string s = reader4["count"].ToString();
    count = int.Parse(s.Trim());
    reader4.Close();
    con.Close();
 }

 con.Open();

 string str = "SELECT Name from [Committee].[dbo].[Supervisor] ;";
 com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
 SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

 string  [] list;
 list = new string [count] ;

 if (reader.Read())
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
         list[i] = reader["Name"].ToString(); // so here I got the problem
     }

     reader.Close();
     con.Close();
 }

 DropDownList1.DataSource = list;
 DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Hello guys, I have this code I'm retrieving a column "Name" from database And I want to bind it in DropdownList1. It works but, I'm getting the only first row from the column. The question is how to save it in the array row by row and bind it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time `SqlDataReader.Read` is called it advances the record to the next row, however you're only calling it once which means each time you access `reader["Name"]` you're getting the first row. Instead of doing an `if/for` you should be calling it in a `while`:

```
var list = new List<string>();
while(reader.Read())
{
    list.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
}
```

It's also probably easier if you use a `List<string>` instead of an array as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    list.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
}

reader.Close(); 
con.Close();
```

This way you don't need the count query because the reader will execute aslong there are rows to return.

ps: If somehow you need an array, you can use the `list.ToArray()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you should use `while` for `reader`  instead of `If`

```
    int i=0;
    while(reader.Read())
     {
         list[i] = reader["Name"].ToString(); 
         i++;
     }
     reader.Close();
     con.Close();
```